# Intellij Idea's console increase max symbols per line

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij idea wraps console output in the run window, how I can increase N after which wrap happens?

[image: weird console output in the run window]

as you can see wrap happened on the last line, how I can configure IDE not to wrap so short lines? I have a lot of free space in this window

P.S. windows, golang plugin for Intellij idea

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's already a ticket for this on the issue tracker of the plugin, please see [this issue](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/1784). However, it's dependent on a platform issue, please see [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117552). My advice would be to track either of the issue in order to know when this is fixed, unfortunately it's not much that the plugin can do right now as far as I can tell.